# WordPress category page. 2 column

Tags: wordpress, layout, categories

I’m hoping someone can help.  I thought it would be superbly easy to find and do.

Basically on the category pages, the default template (one column, ugly) I want to create a two column layout for the category posts page.

Has anyone a simple solution for this??????

I am using elementor free version and astra theme free version.

Thanks again!